# Каким образом при помощи SNMP посмотреть установленные программы в Windows?

Tags: windows, snmp

Каким образом можно найти или узнать OID для просмотра всех установленных в системе программ. Я применил политику установки программы. Чтобы не  проверять на каждом компьютере присутствует ли эта программа, я хочу проверить при помощи SNMP. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, надо установить *на каждый компьютер* **SNMP-службу**. Имеется возможность как автоматизировать установку, так  и произвести удаленную установку.

Затем необходимо настроить **SNMP-агент** *каждого компьютера*, чтобы можно его опрашивать.

И наконец, у Windows нет **встроенного менеджера SNMP**. Однако существуют сторонние и даже бесплатные решения для сбора сведений о системе - это обычно: нагрузка на дисковую подсистему, нагрузка CPU и т.п.

Короче, необходимо как минимум 3 этапа для решения задачи, с использованием технологии SNMP, привлекая сторонние средства.

Comment: Я собираю информацию при помощи PHP. Мне необходим просто OID данной опции.

Comment: Так скорее всего существует прямая зависимость номенклатуры OID от выбранного решения. разобравшись в том, какой менеджер SNMP используется, получите ответ на то, какие данные он собирает.